# How to match up if statements with others

Tags: python, if-statement

I am having issues with this, I cannot get 2 separate if statements to match up with each other. For example, I would like to match up A1==2" with A4=="1".
Please help!!! (Ignore the TROLO, just temp. ending.)

```
print ("You find yourself in a dark room, do you... (1) Try to find a way out... or... (2) Sit down and think.")
A1 = input('>>')
if A1 == '1':
        print ("You go into panic, you begin to feel dizzy and lightheaded...")
        print ("Do you (1) Sit down and try to relax... or... (2) Slow down, but keep searching.")
elif A1 == '2':
        A2 = input('>>')
    print ("You sit down and catch your breath for a minute.")
    print ("Do you (1) Get back up and keep feeling your way around ... or ... (2) Lay down for a mintute or two longer.")
A1 = input('>>')
if A1 == '2':
        print ("You sit down and catch your breath for a minute.")
        print ("Do you (1) Get back up and keep feeling your way around ... or ... (2) Lay down for a mintute or two longer.")

input ("TROLOLOLO")
```

Comment: Please fix the indentation and please explain the problem more clearly

Comment: And if you answered A1 with "2", then I would like it to go to A4

Comment: Then put the `A4` code in the `A1 == '2':` code block :3

Comment: I just started using python very recently, could you pls give an example? Sorry :(

Comment: I must be a real idiot, I still cant get it to work...

Comment: Just make sure your indentation is all accurate (so what you want to run in one section is indented correctly)

Comment: I updated it, is it indentation?

Comment: Are you sure that's your *exact* code? That indentation *definitely* does not look right. Make sure you're not mixing tabs and spaces together

Comment: I mean something like this: http://pastebin.com/N4uDibRg

Comment: It works, I just have no idea how to continue this

Comment: Well continuing it is your idea, it's your code :)

Comment: I mean the actual code, do I just go on to to A4 and skip A1 '2' until I get back to it?

Comment: It really depends on what you're trying to do. If that's what you want to ask the user, then sure. Whatever is indented will run in that specific codeblock

Comment: I dont know why this isnt working... not even going to ask.

Comment: Okay, try and elaborate on how it isn't working. Are you getting an output?

Comment: 1 sec.. I will update the code...

Comment: Okay, now what's happening when you run the script

Comment: I have to press 2 twice, when it actually says something it says "You sit down and catch your breath a minute. Do you... blah blah blah."

Comment: Are you using Python 2 or 3?

Comment: 3, omg that's the issue isnt it...

Comment: Nope, if it was Python 2 then there would be a problem. Also, should `print("You sit down..."` be indented, so it's underneath the `A2 = input('>>')`?

Comment: btw when I press '1' it doesnt work either

Comment: There, indented, do you seen any issues?

Comment: ... hello? Are you still there?

Comment: Sorry I had to go. I really can't see the problem here, the code should work fine. Sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is this:

```
print("You find yourself in a dark room, do you... (1) Try to find a way out... or... (2) Sit down and think.")
A1 = input('>>')
if A1 == '1':
    print ("You go into panic, you begin to feel dizzy and lightheaded...")
    print ("Do you (1) Sit down and try to relax... or... (2) Slow down, but keep      searching.")
elif A2 == '2':
    A4 = input('>>')
    etc
```

`elif` means *else if*. It's part of the same conditional, and so if A1 equals '1', it will do that. *Otherwise, if A2 == '2'*, then ask for `A4`

Comment: Thank you! I think this will help!

Comment: @tedmiston I'm assuming the OP is using python 3, and so `raw_input()` does not exist, and besides, `raw_input()` returns a string in python 2, and `input()` returns an integer (in python 2)

Comment: @Haidro Whoops, let me fix that typo. Good clarification about which version of Python OP may be using.  I should have said  `int(input('some prompt'))` for Python 3 purposes.  Or put the other way, OP should replace `input(...)` in the code above with `raw_input(...)` if using Python 2.7.

Answer (score 0):

Start by fixing those indents and changing the if conditionals to elif.  Also, if you are not landing into your if blocks, look into removing those quotes:

```
if A1 == 1:
```